# How to implement a carousel using VMware clarity?

Tags: angular, vmware, vmware-clarity

I discover this design system today, and I want to move my project from Bootstrap angular wraper library to this one, but there is no carousel component, so there is way for doing this? This is planned for some release?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clarity doesn't have an Carousel Component. You can open a GitHub issue on the Clarity repo to request for one: https://github.com/vmware/clarity

The Clarity UX team will then evaluate your request and respond back with more information.